# ESlint couldn't find eslint package in GitHub Actions, but works locally. (Monorepo)

Tags: reactjs, github, github-actions, eslint, cicd

I am practicing using the monorepo structure with `npm workspace` for the first time. However, now GitHub Actions is giving me the error below.

```
Run npm run lint

> project@ lint /home/runner/work/project/project
> eslint . --fix --ext .js,.jsx

sh: 1: eslint: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! deis-course-evaluation@ lint: `eslint . --fix --ext .js,.jsx`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
```

#### project structure

```
- backend
  - package.json
- frontend
  - package.json
- node_modules
- package.json
- .eslintrc.json
```

#### ci yml file

```
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm install
    - name: Check for bugs and stylistic issues. 
      run: npm run lint
```

#### root package.json file

```
{
    "name": "project",
    "private": true,
    "workspaces": [
        "backend",
        "frontend"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "backend": "cd backend; nodemon ./index.js;",
        "frontend": "cd frontend; npm run dev",
        "doc": "jsdoc -c jsdoc.json",
        "lint": "eslint . --fix --ext .js,.jsx",
        "start": "npm run backend && npm run frontend"
    }
}
```

I have tried installing eslint in the workflow but then it gives me this error.

```
ESLint: 8.43.0

ESLint couldn't find the plugin "eslint-plugin-react-hooks".

(The package "eslint-plugin-react-hooks" was not found when loaded as a Node module from the directory "/home/runner/work/project-name/project-name".)

It's likely that the plugin isn't installed correctly. Try reinstalling by running the following:

    npm install eslint-plugin-react-hooks@latest --save-dev

The plugin "eslint-plugin-react-hooks" was referenced from the config file in ".eslintrc.json".
```

installing the plugin in the workflow doesn't help either.

I've tried to reinstall `node_modules` locally, although `@eslint` and `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` is present in `node_modules`, it still didn't solve the issue during ci.

It seems like this is a problem with `eslint` itself, but I'm wondering if there are any workarounds?